# Custom Actions - Add to Action Menu - ARInvoiceEntry vs. APInvoiceEntry / JournalEntry

Tags: acumatica

I have extension classes for the ARInvoiceEntry, APInvoiceEntry and JournalEntry, each has a action button called “ChangeSomeField”, which needs to be on the Action Menu.

For ARInvoiceEntry, the base class has an ActionsMenuItem.AddMenuAction() which I can use to add the action to the action menu.  From what I can see in the code this is because they ARDataEntryGraph which implements the IActionsMenuGraph.

For both APInvoiceEntry and JournalEntry, from what I can see they’re base classes do not implement this interface which means I can’t access the ActionsMenuItem.AddMenuAction() to add the actions to the action menu.

In APInvoiceEntry and JournalEntry extension classes, how do I add custom actions to the action menu?  Do I need to implement that IActionsMenuGraph myself on my extension classes or is there another way?  Could I please have an example if either of the above two are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the layout editor you can use the Actions section of the screen.

[image]

Here you can add an existing action (which you defined in your graph extension) and define under which "Section" you want it to be shown. This is done by specifying the category as "Actions"

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot this works, was able to add the actions for AP and GL on here and they're displaying on the action menu now.